# Javascript Vue: Where does the variable 'e' in onFileChange(e) originate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Javascript Vue: Where does the variable `e` in `onFileChange(e)` originate?

In the following code, there is a variable `e` in `onFileChange(e)`, where does it originate? It is never declared or imported in the code, so how can it be valid?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<template>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h4>File Upload with VueJS and Laravel</h4>
      <br />
      <div style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div v-if="success !== ''" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          {{success}}
        </div>
        <form @submit="submitForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input
                type="file"
                name="filename"
                class="custom-file-input"
                id="inputFileUpload"
                v-on:change="onFileChange"
              />
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputFileUpload"
                >Choose file</label
              >
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <p class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{filename}}</p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log("Component successfully mounted.");
    },
    data() {
      return {
        filename: "",
        file: "",
        success: ""
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onFileChange(e) {
        //console.log(e.target.files[0]);
        this.filename = "Selected File: " + e.target.files[0].name;
        this.file = e.target.files[0];
      },
      submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let currentObj = this;
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
              .content
          }
        };

        // form data
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", this.file);

        // send upload request
        axios
          .post("/store_file", formData, config)
          .then(function(response) {
            currentObj.success = response.data.success;
            currentObj.filename = "";
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            currentObj.output = error;
          });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: `onFileChange(e) { }` declares a method which takes one parameter. That parameter is simply named `e` but it could also be named `banana` - it matters little, since it's just a label. There doesn't need to be anything special to declare a parameter - if you have a `function plusOne(x) { return x + 1; }` you have a function that takes one parameter named `x` but you don't have to declare it anywhere but the function itself. Same thing with `onFileChange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That declaration is triggered by your template, where you are binding `change` event to the method. The whole event as parameter gets passed to the method, Refer this section of `Vue docs` for better information https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is called `e` it is usually the event. You can always `console.log(e)` and read its properties in the browser console.

But according to this [example](https://vuejsexamples.com/file-upload-component-for-vue-js/) `e` is the file that is uploaded:

```
methods: {
  thumbUrl (file) {
    return file.myThumbUrlProperty
  },
  onFileChange (file) {
    // Handle files like:
    this.fileUploaded = file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onFileChange(e)` has `e` as `event` related to the dom. Since while assigning the function in `html` if there is no parameter passed, the `event` as a parameter is automatically passed by javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `onFileChange(e) {`

declares a function with the name `onFileChange` that takes a single parameter `e`. That is what introduces the variable into the function body.

Comment: @65535 an event. It's called when a change event occurs, so you get the change event itself.